# Creating texts and buttons with listeners successively?

Tags: android, button, listener

I will try to explain my problem. The code below as you can see try to add some textviews and buttons as the array get from another class.

```
public class Breakfast extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        sv.addView(ll);
        if (extras != null) {

             String food[]=extras.getStringArray("food");       
             String foodCateg[]=extras.getStringArray("foodCateg");

             int K=0;

             for (int i = 0; i < food.length/3; i++) {
                 TextView foodDay = new TextView(this);
                 foodDay.setText("Day "+ (i+1));    
                 ll.addView(foodDay);

                 for (int j=K;j<K+3;j++){
                     Button contfood= new Button(this);
                     contfood.setText(food[j]);
                     ll.addView(contfood);
                 }
                 K=K+3;         
             }
             this.setContentView(sv);
         }
    }
```

My question is how can I know what of this buttons are clicked on the screen?? Because in the case of what one of them are clicked (getting the text that have write before), I will do something or other thing.

---

ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh yes I know how to do a ListActivity. But first I think in doing by hand because I don´t think how to symplify this...

Thank you for the answers of trying to build with everything a listview and then the method OnListItemClick, but I think that isn´t the solution.

I said that because when I insert the day for example (I Don´t put hear all the code...) but I do .setgravity .setSize .setbackgroundResource etc. And with the food for that day I use a diferent .setgravity and more parameters. So I think that with listview everything would have the same specifications... and that´s what I don´t like.

so... to know what button is pressed on the screen?

Comment: You say it. A *NEW* question. Please ask it separately and accept an adequeate answer.

Comment: I don´t think that is a new question, first I said that could be a new, but then I finally arrive to the conclusion that my question is the same as the first post. But I will edit...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`contfood.setId(i)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) and work your way from there.

But what you are doing looks like you really want to create a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and use it's [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

Comment: I was going to post just that! Follow this advice! Use a ListView, don't try doing it by hand. Otherwise it will come back to bite you later down the road.

Comment: +1, ListView / ListActivity can be a bit complex at first, but once you get it, it's a lot easier and "good practice" than doing it by hand

Comment: soooo I think that the best answer to my question is to implement a contfood.setid(i) inside the for. But then how can I call to the button general that is clicked?

Comment: Although I still recommend using a `ListActivity` you can get the view id within the `onClick` method of the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: I add the id for every button I create. But now how can I refere to this buttons with the onclicklistener in the code I wrote? Excuse me...

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is put an id to each button "contfood". And then when you click on a button retrieve the id back to do the action you want.

Another way is to create the button and attach the method public void onClick(View view):

```
for (int j=K;j<K+3;j++){
                 Button contfood= new Button(this);
                 contfood.setText(food[j]);
                 ll.addView(contfood);

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), xxx.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
          }
}
```

and add the parameters within the method.

Comment: excuse me but this doesn´t work because the onClick have to be putted outside the oncreate method. I think that the best answer would be to implement an id for every button I build (I have already do), and my problem cames when I have to say how of this buttons were pressed!